# Git Push Error ( Local to Remote ) in VPS Git Server?

Tags: django, git, github, push, vps

I've written a small `django` site in my Mac(Sierra OS), and I wanna to put it in my new `vps(digital ocean CentOS 7)`. I have successfully created git server there.

My local django project has an local git repository，I set remote url to my centOS git server site. And everything is going well..   I push my project to the server …  and finally, it is weird that when the push task has done, I enter the remote file, and found that **the ‘push task’ has only push my local .git file directory to the server**.. **and any other project file is ignored!**   Even later, I added more commits, but those  made no difference.

I tried to create a new repo in github.com. and push my project to the github in the exactly same way, but **it works well in the github platform --- all of my project files have sucessfully pushed to the github server.**

How could I solve the problem?

Comment: The output when you pushed to your digital ocean repo would help troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: Do you see any errors when the push competes? The best thing would be to copy and paste all the steps you're doing from your terminal window, complete with the output. Are you certain that the `.git` directory in the remote server is the same as your local one? If you created a repo on your remote server, that will have its own `.git` directory, which is probably what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall your vps and setup again git server.

After setup new server try to push by ssh with debug, for example:

```
git add *
git commit -m "Commit description"
GIT_TRACE=1 git push origin master
```